# How to clone a VM, without purchasing additional tool?

Tags: virtual-machine, esxi, cloning

I am looking for a free way to clone a machine in `vsphere`.

I am using `ESXI 5.0`, I cannot seem to find that option.

All my research lead to commercial packages.

Do I need to pay to have that feature?

**I need free solution, please do not point me to paid one.**

It mentions the following

> You must be connected to vCenter Server in order to clone a virtual
>   machine. You cannot clone virtual machines if you connect directly to
>   an ESXi host.

Then I looked into vCenter, to my [surprise](http://store.vmware.com/store/vmware/en_US/cat/ThemeID.2485600/categoryID.66249000?src=WWW_eBIZ_productpage_vCenter_Standard_Buy_US#pid-282870000), it cost `$6,044.00`

Not trying to be cheap, I don't have this budget yet.

Comment: This question is still not on topic on this website.

Comment: Just copy the vmdk file?  Or, give up on ESXi, and switch over to Hyper-V, which is also free, and provides a lot more useful functionality at the base level.

Comment: @Ramhound what exactly is off topic, its easy to criticize, harder to explain.

Comment: @AlPacino - per the flag/close resaons:  "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. I"

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I am asking **HOW TO CLONE** , its not a product, not asking learning material. I am asking how to do it, if it is not possible then its fine, I dont ask for other tool. Jeez!

Comment: `I need free alternatives`.  So that's *not* asking for product recommendations then?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables not necessarily, for example [zoredache](http://superuser.com/questions/751398/how-to-clone-a-vm-without-purchasing-additional-tool?noredirect=1#comment970623_751398) had a good suggestion to copy files. This is the type of answer I am looking for, not police comments that are not helping me

Comment: You specifically request software free software and the only way to answer that request is a product recommendation which is not on topic I don't critique.  Modify the question so it's not a request for software and I will retract my close vote

Comment: Don't be picky about the wording guys. It's clear that OP is simply looking for any way to clone the VM, not specifically for a pre-made software for that. Remember that we're here to help. Sometimes question may need little adjustments to make it sound on-topic, in those cases just use the Edit button and be nice for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I`m probably going to get a hand-slap by others, but hey - just helping...

Look here, this guy details how to copy and generalize the image to a template. And before anyone asks, I have done this with older VM workstation and vSphere installation. This guy outlines the instructions better than I can... :-)

[Cloning a VM without vcenter in ESXi](http://nchrissos.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/cloning-a-vm-without-vcenter-in-esxi-5-1-free-edition/)

Update: 
Very well - must adhere to etiquette then..

1. in vSphere client shutdown the vmware image in question (power down)
2. Select config tab and the storage settings and browse/explore
3. Copy the root folder by right-clicking and give the copy a new name (Example: copy_template_image).
4. Select the config file (.vmx) and the virtual disk file (.vmdk) - control button [ctrl] to multi-select and ctrl-c to copy the items.
5. Paste the two items to the destination folder.
6. Copy the .vmx file to the Inventory.
7. Enter a new name for the cloned VM
8. Use the sysprep utility to generalize the VM.

Comment: Link-only answers are a no-no. Please include pertinent information directly in your answer(s).

Comment: That's it , that's all I asked for. You have provided me with what I needed without judging. Cheers!